# Using System.Diagnostics C++.Net 2003 fx1.1

Tags: c++, c#-3.0, clickonce

When ClickOnce deploys apps, it generates an .application file that allows you to execute the application, so the main application is builded on C++.Net 2003 using Fx1.1, when I told him that call the first file (.application file from ClickOnce Deployment C# 3.0 app) he didnt know how ¿?!

I trying to write some code snippet, the code below cant "open" the .application file generated from ClickOnce.. Thanks

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             System::Diagnostics::Process app ;
             app.StartInfo->FileName = "C:\INFORME\SRIMedico.application";
             app.StartInfo->Arguments = "";
             app.Start();

         }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear to me what is it exactly that you're looking for but as far as I know ClickOnce it not meant to be used to deploy VC++ applications.

See [ClickOnce Deployment For Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235287(VS.80).aspx)

Edit:

There's one thing that jumps out at me in your code example: You have not escaped the "\" character (which is a special character in C++) and in which case the path you supplied would be invalid. Please re-try it like this:

```
    // .. rest of code in your sample ommited 
    app.StartInfo->FileName = "C:\\INFORME\\SRIMedico.application";
    // .. rest of code in your sample ommited
```

Another thing that I overlooked earlier is that while you may use System::Diagnostics::Process to launch a ClickOnce application installer, it only works using the location where you originally installed the application from, not the location where the application was installed.  See the [Remarks section in the Process.StartInfo documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx#remarksToggle).

You may also use the **.appref-ms** application reference file to launch the application, if you have it installed on the computer. Assuming this file is located in C:\INFORME\ you may write something like this:

```
    System::Diagnostics::Process^ app = gcnew System::Diagnostics::Process()
    app->StartInfo->FileName = "C:\\INFORME\\SRIMedico.appref-ms";
    app->StartInfo->Arguments = "";
    app->StartInfo->CreateNoWindow = "false";
    app->Start();
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: SRIMedico is and .application file generated by Deploying a C# 3.0 Application with ClickOnce